# Atom Emmet Custom HTML snippets.json shortcut elements on multi line

Tags: html, atom-editor, emmet

**I'm trying to create an Emmet (+TAB) shortcut and I have 90% of it complete. I just can't figure out how to get the last nested elements to be on their own lines. The label, input and closing div tag are all on one line. I'd like to have them all on separate lines**

*snippet.json code*

```
"form+": "section.form-container>div.form-wrapper>form:post>(div.form-group>label+inp)+btn:s"
```

*html*

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>


  <section class="form-container">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group"><label for=""></label><input type="text" name="" id=""></div>
        <button type="submit"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>
```

**Trying to get it to look like this automatically**

```
  <section class="form-container">
    <div class="form-wrapper">
      <form action="" method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label for=""></label>
          <input type="text" name="" id="">
        </div>
        <button type="submit"></button>
      </form>
    </div>
  </section>


</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the element layout is controlled by `inline_break` option of [output profile](https://docs.emmet.io/customization/syntax-profiles/), which acts globally for all snippets expanded by Emmet. You can reduce `inline_break` to `2`, it will cause elements to lay out as expected

Comment: I added the **syntaxProfiles.json** file to the following path **/users/username/.atom/packages/emmet** with the following syntax                        ```{
  "html":{
    "inline_break":"2"
    }
}
``` Is this correct? I'm not getting any changes to syntax behavior